# Post base64 string to MVC controller after conversion

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

On the client side, I am allowing the user to upload an image which is then converted into a base64 image. I want to then send this to a controller, which will then rebuild the image, but I am struggling to pass the base64 string to the controller correctly.

I am not convinced I am doing this in the best way as well.

Here is the HTML page:

```
<form id="qrForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label class="btn btn-default btn-file btn-block btn-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span>
        Begin
        <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" name="file" id="file" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL();" style="display: none;">
    </label>
</form>

<form id="base64Form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" id="base64Img" name="base64Img" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function encodeImageFileAsURL()
{
    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("file").files;

    if (filesSelected.length > 0)
    {
        var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = function (fileLoadedEvent)
        {
            var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

            var newImage = document.createElement('img');
            newImage.src = srcData;

            console.log("Converted Base64 version is " + newImage.outerHTML);

            document.getElementById("base64Img").value = newImage.outerHTML;
            document.forms["base64Form"].submit();
        }

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    }
}

</script>
```

Here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string base64Img)
{
    if (base64Img.Length > 0)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to waste cpu and more bandwidth with sending it as base64 and not as formdata?

Comment: @Endless Would it be better to just send it as the exact image file as it is originally? I thought that a base64 image would use less bandwidth?

Comment: quite the opposite a base64 is ~3x larger in size... And in javascript it will take up 2x more memory since strings are utf16 and not utf8

Comment: @Endless that saves me a lot of hassle - thanks for the advice!

Comment: Also take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/fdzmd4mg/1/